# codeigniter db->select handle mysql joins automaticly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, left-join

### table

```
ID|owner_id|work_id|lorem|etc|
1 |00123   | 00213 |XXXXX|XXX|
2 |00124   | 00213 |XXXXX|XXX|

owner_id (fk) owners.id (owners[id,name,etc])

work_id (fk) work.id (work[id,name,etc])
```

question is can I set `codeigniter` that when I

```
select(table.*,work.name as work,owners.name as owner) from table
```

it automatically handle joins since that table already contain the fk-ref ? or I must include `join('owner','owner.id=table.owner_id)` ?

actually all what I want is that when I select a table that contains a fk this fk column is replaced with one column from ref row by just passing the column name on ref table without having to worry about creating a specific function in my module for that each query.

**My current solution:**

was to create a view for each table that contain a relation and replace all fk columns with desired ref value, but since i have 6 tables 5 of them with fk,i now have 6 tables and 5 view (11 tables)in db which is really kind confusing for me, so any smarter way to do this ?

Comment: if so then the only actual benefit of setting relations is to cascade actions ! other wise i can just do 2 separate select queries first to get main row and second to get required ref value with simple where id=fk ! is that's right ?

Comment: Or you can use one join statement to do them both on a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making some confusion on what FK is and what it does within a table.

FK constraint grants data integrity when it's present and relates data within tables. It doesn't join anything.

If you want to select records across related tables, you either use a

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.K1 = table2.FK1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.K1 = table2.FK1
```

AND YES, you need to tell CodeIgniter to do those queries

Comment: I'll add that constructing your queries in SQL before using CodeIgniter is a good practice and it's then easier to write down code .